# Newly Created Firebase Functions Throwing UNAUTHENTICATED Error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase project with over 10 cloud functions. Today I added 3 more, but all three of the new ones are throwing an error UNAUTHENTICATED without actually trying to hit the function. (There's no record of a function call in the logs). I haven't made any changes to my environment or Firebase project since adding the previous functions.

I have tried redeploying all of the functions in my project, the three newest ones continue to fail while the previous ones work fine. I have also verified that I am using Node 8, since there are some similar issues reported stemming from using Node 10. I am not sure what else to try since the issue only applies to the new functions.

The new functions all have a similar signature:

```
exports.createGroup = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  //Firestore access
});
```

They are being called like this:

```
const create = functions().httpsCallable('createGroup');
return create({ group: oGroup }).then(result => {
      //Do something
}).catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message); //UNAUTHENTICATED
});
```

Node Version: 8.16.2

Firebase Tools Version: 7.6.1

Comment: Contact Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I've disabled "Cloud Scheduler API" and then reenabled it. After that it started working.

Comment: Disable and enable Cloud Scheduler API, it worked for me too!

Here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com/overview

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Via Google Cloud docs:

> As of January 15, 2020, HTTP functions require authentication by
>   default. You can specify whether a function allows unauthenticated
>   invocation at or after deployment.

The solution was to utilize the Google Cloud console (NOT the Firebase console) to add the `allUsers` permission to the newly created functions.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation

Comment: Do we have to do this manually for every new function forever?

Comment: Interestingly I actually haven't had to manually do this since then. I am using Node 10 for my functions. No clue if that matters or not.

Comment: i have allow access but still have same issue

Answer (score 40):

## 2024 UPDATE

1. Open the *Cloud Functions* page in the Google Cloud Console: https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list.
2. Click the checkbox next to the function to which you want to grant access.
3. Click *Permissions* at the top of the screen. The Permissions panel opens.
4. Click *Add principal*.
5. In the *New principals* field, type `allUsers`.
6. Select the role *Cloud Functions* > *Cloud Functions Invoker* from the *Select a role* drop-down menu.
7. Click *Save*.

Comment: Does allUsers include unauthenticated users? i.e. anyone could call my function?

Comment: If i did this is my functions and database is secured?

Comment: "Error: Principals of type allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers cannot be added to this resource"

Comment: @David youre probaly using 2nd gen functions. Just figure it out how to solve it on mine by selecting at least one 1st gen function and then add public permissions (allUsers) to both at same time

Comment: same as @David here. I'm using 1st gen. I have many functions that are called by tasks and I always was able to add allAuthenticatedUsers and remove allUsers but I couldn't on this recently deployed function

Comment: This is very odd, I have multiple firebase projects where my functions are public but for some reason one project does not have this public access, I searched way too long for the reason why my function is not working

Comment: In my case I had to remove allUsers first then re-add. I think it was initially caused by a failure the first time I uploaded the function.

Comment: this didn't fix it for me

Answer (score 24):

It must be solved at your [GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions) Console (not Firebase). Just follow these steps:

1. Go to your [GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions) and login
2. On the top menu, select the corresponding Firebase project
3. On the left menu go to Cloud Functions Click the checkbox of your function (not the name of the function)
4. Once selected, on the right menu select "Add member"
5. On "New member" type allUsers
6. On the Select function bar, select Cloud Functions -> Cloud functions invoker
7. Click on "Save" and then "Allow public access" on the pop-up warning
   And you're good to go!

Comment: any way to automate this?

Comment: Thanks, You definitely have deserved this upvote :)

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this error when deploying several functions and there was an  issue during the upload where it seems the deployment got corrupted *.. perhaps network related, not sure*

After deleting the offending cloud functions in the Firebase console, and then doing a fresh successful deploy for them, the **"FirebaseFunctionsException UNAUTHENTICATED"** error went away

First I tried to just redeploy the functions, but that was not enough, the error continued this way

Comment: This happened to me when my deployment failed. Then when I successfully deployed, it changed my setting to require authentication.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation for [2nd gen Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#after_deployment):

> 1. Go to the [Google Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/)
> 2. Click the linked name of the function to which you want to grant access.
> 3. Click the **Powered By Cloud Run** link in the top right corner of the Function details overview page.
> 4. Click **Trigger** and select **Allow unauthenticated invocations**.
> 5. Click **Save**.

Took me forever to find this after trying to add allUsers and getting "Principals of type allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers cannot be added to this resource".

Comment: This answer may be true for 2nd gen functions, but for 1st gen functions there is no "Powered By Cloud Run" link. For 1st gen functions follow the previous answer of adding allUsers principal. I looked at both answers (without thinking about if my functions were 1st gen or 2nd), tried this one first, was confused about why I could not find the Powered By link until I figured out the difference.

Comment: You can select Allow unauthenticated invocations in Security tab now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this did the trick but it seemed to work. I had the **allUsers** permission set in Google Cloud Console for my function with the Role "**Cloud Functions Invoker**" set by default, but it was not working - UNAUTHENTICATED error.

I commented out my new function locally, deployed again, was asked if I want to delete it from the CLI - Said yes..

Then uncommented the function and deployed again.
(I tried deleting from Firebase too but that didnt work.)

I then went back to Google Cloud Console (**Function Details -> Permissions**) and edited the **allUsers** permission and added an additional Role ("**Cloud Functions Admin**"). As below..

[image]

Tested and it worked.

Then I deleted the "**Cloud Functions Admin**" Role (for safety) and just left the "**Cloud Functions Invoker**" Role.
Now it works. Dont know why this happened, hopefully doesnt happen again...