# Firebase-Function - Scheduled Function keep throwing a error "UNAUTHENTICATED"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am making a "scheduled" firebase-function that gets data from external API source and save it at firestore.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { default: Axios } = require("axios");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.getIndexData = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun(async() => {

  try {
    const response = await Axios(
      "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quotes/index?apikey=myAPIKEY"
    );
    const data = response.data;

    const writeResult = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("index")
      .doc("sorted-index")
      .set({ indexData: data,timeStamp:Date.now()});

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } 
  return null;

});
```

this is my firebase-function code. and it works totally fine when I run the function separately, and also I tested the function with "google cloud platform cloud function test". Data is successfully set it at firestore when I run a function seperately.

However, it doesn't work when I deploy the function, and I think it is about scheduled-function stuff

```
{
  "insertId": "184t0npf9hhej7",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "pubsubTopic": "projects/my-project/topics/firebase-schedule-getIndexData-us-central1",
    "targetType": "PUB_SUB",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "jobName": "projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/jobs/firebase-schedule-getIndexData-us-central1",
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
    "labels": {
      "job_id": "firebase-schedule-getIndexData-us-central1",
      "project_id": "my-project",
      "location": "us-central1"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2020-12-09T08:48:01.142830977Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/my-project/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2020-12-09T08:48:01.142830977Z"
}
```

So I was keep searching for this UNAUTHENTICATED  error, and people says I hvae to change some permission options. so I gave allUsers and allAuthenticated Users a Cloud Functions Invoker permission. still not working.

Any Idea or solution on this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of your problem but you should only do `return null;` when all the asynchronous work is completed. Concretely you should move the `return null;` just after `const writeResult = await admin...` in the `try()`. and you should also add it after the `console.log()` in the `catch()`.

Comment: Can you correctly view the topic and the function as it is indicated (are the logs in the cloud scheduler more clear about the issue?) https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#deploy_a_scheduled_function

Comment: @Juancki I somehow achieved same result by using function.https thing and set google scheduler to get the url every 5mins instead of pubsub. But still not working with pubsub thing.. pubsub keep sending this UNAUTHENTICATED error code. I am keep digging it.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I will try. the function worked fine with the test in google cloud.

Comment: I'm facing same issue here, I contacted firebase support so they asked for logs files... still waiting for a response from them.

Comment: @attakon Same here, did you get any response from firebase support?

Comment: It got fixed automatically for me today without doing anything

Comment: we do have same problem with 2 brand new projects. We created another one = didn't have the prob. Create another one => had the prod! So it is very random!

Comment: @Alejov it got fixed as well for me. No answers from support team so far

Comment: I just encountered the very same problem. We did new re-deploy of all functions before the failure but the one under pub sob had no changes. I believe this is a bug in GCP...

Answer (score 5):

Try these steps

Disable and re-enable [Cloud Scheduler API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com/overview).

If you are still getting the issue, [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71187462) and repeat the above step.

Comment: Disabling and enabling the `Cloud Scheduler API` worked well for me!
Thanks a lot

Comment: This worked for me also. I disabled and then redeployed all cloud functions for good measure. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to include "context" in your arguments.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

```
.onRun(async (context) => { ... })
```

Comment: I was very skeptical of this answer since I was not using any arguments, and Javascript does not impose any argument restrictions.. But it somehow fixed it for me? I am using typescript, and exporting the method from another file like this `export async function myFunction(context: EventContext) { }`