# Firebase Cloud Scheduler error: Not found

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have followed [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions?gen=2nd) example using 2nd gen Cloud Functions. My code is very simple at the moment:

```
"use strict";

const {onSchedule} = require("firebase-functions/v2/scheduler");
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");

exports.onScheduleEvent = onSchedule("every 2 minutes", async (event) => {
  logger.log("Scheduled event fired");
});
```

I have deployed this to a project on the Blaze Plan. It sort of works, in the Cloud Scheduler Jobs section I can see that the following is logged every 2 minutes:

```
type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptStarted
type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished
```

However, the latter log (`AttemptFinished`) gives the error:

```
status: "NOT_FOUND"
targetType: "HTTP"
```

I have tried giving `allUsers` the `Cloud functions invoker` permission and setting `Allow unauthenticated invocations` to true in the Cloud Run console, according to the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151247/newly-created-firebase-functions-throwing-unauthenticated-error/74555845#74555845) question. None of this helped, the error persists and I cannot see my own log being printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by disabling and re-enabling the Cloud Scheduler API based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74375080/16168841) answer. The Cloud function was also redeployed from the terminal.