# Cannot execute cloud functions in firebase emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am trying to use the Firebase emulator to deploy my firebase flutter app, and everything works fine except when I call a method that calls a cloud function. I get an error `[firebase_functions/unauthenticated] Unauthenticated` and my cloud function doesn't execute(the rest of the method executes fine). I don't have this problem if I do it in production mode. At first I thought it was a security rules problem so I did:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /{document=**} {

  allow read, write: if true;
}

}
}
```

but still didn't work. I also tried this thread [Newly Created Firebase Functions Throwing UNAUTHENTICATED Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151247/newly-created-firebase-functions-throwing-unauthenticated-errorallowing) and allowed all users to access the cloud functions but still didn't work. I don't know why is this happening in the emulator and not in production mode, and how to solve it. Help please.

Comment: maybe a small confusion, rules handles access only on collection/document firebase/firetore-database, regarding cloud-function security are managed by token in http request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I was not accesing the cloud functions from the emulator. I was accesing the real cloud functions from my production enviroment. I am working in flutter so I solved it by adding

```
FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor( region :  "europe-west1");
functions.useFunctionsEmulator('localhost', 5001);
var delete = functions.httpsCallable(deleteShoppingListsCollectionsFunction).call(data);
```

Before that what I was doing was:

```
var delete = FirebaseFunctions
         .instanceFor( region :  "europe-west1")
         .httpsCallable(deleteShoppingListsCollectionsFunction).call(data);
```

Comment: For people having this problem and reading this. This answer is not entirely correct. You don't need to use the same exact instance to call your callable function. You just need to set your region. So if you have a specific region, this is essential: `FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west1')` instead of just `FirebaseFunctions.instance`.