# Not able to add allUsers to newly created gen 1 Firebase function in us-central1

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase project that has been running for more than a year, and I've added functions on a monthly basis without issue. This week I've made two new HTTP triggered functions, but I am not able to add the `allUsers` principal with the `Cloud Function Invoker` role. I am getting this error:

> Error: Principals of type allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers cannot be added to this resource

Notable info:

- The functions are of Gen 1
- The functions are located in `us-central1`
- The project is not part of an Organization, and thus the public data sharing settings mentioned some places should not be an issue.
- The trigger looks like this (I just replaced function and handler name):
- The runtime is Node 14

```
exports.FUNCTIONNAME = functions
    .https
    .onRequest(async (request, response) => HANDLERNAME(request, response))
```

I've tried the different approaches from the following question, but to no avail. [Newly Created Firebase Functions Throwing UNAUTHENTICATED Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151247/newly-created-firebase-functions-throwing-unauthenticated-error)

In the 2023 update thread user Pedro Andrade is having the same issue as me.
I am sending a support request to Firebase in parallell with this question (through this link https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support)

Comment: Just bumped into the same issue today.
In my case I'm trying to use functions V2 on Node 18. Any clue about how to fix it?

Comment: Not really, the issue just went away by itself after a couple of days

Answer (score 1):

This problem went away and everything works as normal now (after a couple of days)

Comment: Hi, I still have the issue, is it OK for you or not now?