# Flutter failed to call callable cloud function with error [firebase_functions/permission-denied] PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: typescript, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm having this error when trying to call a callable function from Flutter:

```
W/FirebaseContextProvider( 3655): Error getting App Check token. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed.
D/TrafficStats( 3655): tagSocket(294) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
E/flutter ( 3655): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/permission-denied] PERMISSION_DENIED
E/flutter ( 3655):
E/flutter ( 3655): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
message_codecs.dart:653
E/flutter ( 3655): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
platform_channel.dart:315
E/flutter ( 3655): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3655): #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call
method_channel_https_callable.dart:22
E/flutter ( 3655): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3655): #3      HttpsCallable.call
https_callable.dart:49
E/flutter ( 3655): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3655): #4      _SendFeedbackModalBottomSheetState.build.<anonymous closure>
send_feedback.dart:90
E/flutter ( 3655): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3655):
E/flutter ( 3655): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
message_codecs.dart:653
E/flutter ( 3655): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
platform_channel.dart:315
E/flutter ( 3655): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3655): #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call
method_channel_https_callable.dart:22
E/flutter ( 3655): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3655): #3      HttpsCallable.call
https_callable.dart:49
E/flutter ( 3655): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3655): #4      _SendFeedbackModalBottomSheetState.build.<anonymous closure>
send_feedback.dart:90
E/flutter ( 3655): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3655):
```

Here's how the callable function is called:

```
                  final HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('sendFeedback');
                  final resp = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
                    'email': 'customer@example.com',
                    'message': message,
                  });
```

Here's how the cloud function looks like:

```
const sendgridApiKey = functions.config().sendgrid.key;
sgMail.setApiKey(sendgridApiKey);
export const sendFeedback = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Check if the user is authenticated
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unauthenticated", "User is not authenticated");
  }

  const message = data.message;

  try {
    // Compose the email message
    const emailMessage = {
      to: "hello@example.com",
      from: "no-reply@example.com",
      subject: "Feedback from user",
      text: message,
    };

    // Send the email using SendGrid
    await sgMail.send(emailMessage);

    return {
      success: true, message: "Email sent successfully",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending email:", error);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", "An error occurred while sending the email");
  }
});
```

This happens on the simulator and on a real device. I have checked the service account "App Engine default service account" and its role is "Editor". Is there anything missing that I need to do to fix that permission error?

Update: I tried to use App Check debug token today as directed in https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider#android and did not see the error "Error getting App Check token. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed" anymore. But the permission denied error still happened.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I could resolve the error by adding role `Cloud Functions Invoker` with the `allUsers` principal to the function.

Comment: If somebody wants more details, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71187462/1790381