# How to force a Firebase first-gen Scheduled Cloud Function to invoke through a specified IAM principal?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-iam

I deployed a first-gen Firebase Scheduled Cloud Function that generates the unauthenticated error. The best fix that I could find was to allow unauthenticated invocation of the function using [the official instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#after_deployment). However, on the face of it, this doesn't seem particularly secure. Is there a way to force this function to be invoked through a specified IAM principal? Or is the official documentation suggestion, to grant all users access to invoke this function, not an unsafe practice?

Or are these scheduled cloud functions always invoked without authentication and that's that?

Comment: What is your definition of "safe" or "secure" for this function?  If the permissions granted by allUsers doesn't match that definition, then it's not safe. Security is a deep and complex topic, and can't be distilled down to a binary.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that Firebase deployed functions should have everything set up for you to be working correctly without your intervention.  If you're suggesting that this is not the case, that's a different problem entirely.  You should probably list out the steps you took to get to the point and see if someone can verify if maybe you did something wrong or your expectations are incorrect.

Comment: @DougStevenson my definition here is purely a relative one. The unauthenticated error is not uncommon (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151247/newly-created-firebase-functions-throwing-unauthenticated-error/71187462#71187462) and the remedy, according to the official doc, is to take this extra step of adding all users as a principal to invoke these functions. This extra step is what I had some concern about. But if your point is that scheduled functions should work out of the box without the need to grant all users this special role then I should probably contact support.

Comment: The deployment should work all of the time, as long as instructions are followed exactly.  It's chance of working should be absolutely 100%, not a "not uncommon" probability.  If it's not 100%, then there is a problem.