# cloud function error INTERNAL for flutter/firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have successfully deployed cloud function in firebase and can see it in firebase console, but when I try to run this through my flutter app via:

```
HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('getSecret');
                            final results = await callable.call();
```

Cloud function is:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import {SecretManagerServiceClient} from "@google-cloud/secret-manager";

const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();

export const getSecret = functions.region('us-central1').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  const [version] = await client.accessSecretVersion({
    name: "projects/project-id/secrets/api/versions/latest",
  });

  const secretValue = version.payload?.data ?? "No found";


  console.log(secretValue);

  return secretValue;
});
```

I got error:

```
W/m.xo.healthSca(14003): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/DynamiteModule(14003): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(14003): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(14003): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
E/flutter (14003): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/unauthenticated] UNAUTHENTICATED
E/flutter (14003): 
E/flutter (14003): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
E/flutter (14003): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
E/flutter (14003): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14003): #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:22:24)
E/flutter (14003): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14003): #3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49:37)
E/flutter (14003): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14003): #4      _ProfileScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:healthhelper/pages/profile/profile_screen.dart:113:45)
E/flutter (14003): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14003): 
E/flutter (14003): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
E/flutter (14003): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
E/flutter (14003): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14003): #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:22:24)
E/flutter (14003): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14003): #3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49:37)
E/flutter (14003): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14003): #4      _ProfileScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:healthhelper/pages/profile/profile_screen.dart:113:45)
E/flutter (14003): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14003):
```

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71187462/19815795) mentioned that I need to set permission in https://console.cloud.google.com/,

1. So my first question is, this solution to set allUser permission allUsers/ Cloud Functions Invoker safe?
2. I got this error - `[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception:` , and no further clue:

   E/flutter (16050): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/internal] INTERNAL
   E/flutter (16050):
   E/flutter (16050): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
   E/flutter (16050): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
   E/flutter (16050): 
   E/flutter (16050): #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:22:24)
   E/flutter (16050): 
   E/flutter (16050): #3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49:37)
   E/flutter (16050): 
   E/flutter (16050): #4      _ProfileScreenState.build.. (package:healthhelper/pages/profile/profile_screen.dart:113:45)
   E/flutter (16050): 
   E/flutter (16050):
   E/flutter (16050): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
   E/flutter (16050): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
   E/flutter (16050): 
   E/flutter (16050): #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:22:24)
   E/flutter (16050): 
   E/flutter (16050): #3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49:37)
   E/flutter (16050): 
   E/flutter (16050): #4      _ProfileScreenState.build.. (package:healthhelper/pages/profile/profile_screen.dart:113:45)
   E/flutter (16050): 
   E/flutter (16050):