firebase [firebase_functions/unauthenticated]
I use flutter and firebase. I'm trying to receive notification by using functions, but i got the follow error :
I/flutter ( 3555): DEBUG: Error sending notification: [firebase_functions/unauthenticated] The function must be called while authenticated.
See my index.js :
// Import Firebase Functions V2 and Firebase Admin SDK
const { onDocumentCreated } = require('firebase-functions/v2/firestore');
const { https } = require('firebase-functions/v2');
const { setGlobalOptions } = require('firebase-functions/v2');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

// Initialize Firebase Admin SDK with explicit credential
// This ensures proper initialization even in local development
if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
  });
}

// Set global options
setGlobalOptions({
  region: "europe-west2",
  maxInstances: 10
});

exports.sendChallengeNotification = https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Validate authentication
  if (!context || !context.auth || !context.auth.uid) {
    throw new https.HttpsError(
      'unauthenticated',
      'The function must be called while authenticated.'
    );
  }
    print("adversaryToken: $adversaryToken");
    print("title: $title");
    print("body: $body");

  // Validate required parameters
  const { adversaryToken, title, body } = data;
  if (!adversaryToken || !title || !body) {
    throw new https.HttpsError(
      'invalid-argument',
      'Missing required parameters: adversaryToken, title, or body'
    );
  }

  try {
    // Get sender's information
    const senderDoc = await admin.firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(context.auth.uid)
      .get();

    if (!senderDoc.exists) {
      throw new https.HttpsError('not-found', 'Sender profile not found');
    }

    const senderData = senderDoc.data();

    const message = {
      notification: {
        title: title,
        body: body,
      },
      data: {
        senderUid: context.auth.uid,
        senderName: senderData.name || 'Unknown User',
        type: 'challenge',
        timestamp: Date.now().toString()
      },
      token: adversaryToken,
      android: {
        priority: 'high',
        notification: {
          clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
        }
      },
      apns: {
        payload: {
          aps: {
            sound: 'default'
          }
        }
      }
    };

    const response = await admin.messaging().send(message);

    // Log the successful notification
    await admin.firestore().collection('notifications').add({
      sender: context.auth.uid,
      token: adversaryToken,
      title: title,
      body: body,
      timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      status: 'sent',
      messageId: response
    });

    return {
      success: true,
      messageId: response,
      timestamp: Date.now()
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in sendChallengeNotification:', error);

    // Log the failed notification
    await admin.firestore().collection('notifications').add({
      sender: context.auth.uid,
      token: adversaryToken,
      title: title,
      body: body,
      timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      status: 'failed',
      error: error.message
    });

    throw new https.HttpsError(
      'internal',
      'Failed to send notification',
      error.message
    );
  }
});

See my flutter function :
  Future<void> sendNotificationToAdversary(String adversaryUserID, String title, String body) async {
    try {
      print("DEBUG: Received parameters - adversaryUserID: $adversaryUserID, title: $title, body: $body");

      if (adversaryUserID.isEmpty) {
        print("DEBUG: AdversaryUserID is empty. Exiting.");
        return;
      }

      // Ensure Firebase is initialized
      if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
        await Firebase.initializeApp();
      }

      // Check authentication
      User? currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      if (currentUser == null) {
        print("DEBUG: User is not authenticated.");
        throw FirebaseAuthException(code: 'unauthenticated', message: 'Please log in.');
      }
      print("DEBUG: Authenticated user ID: ${currentUser.uid}");

      // Retrieve adversary FCM token
      DocumentSnapshot userDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(adversaryUserID).get();
      if (!userDoc.exists) {
        print("DEBUG: No user found with ID: $adversaryUserID.");
        return;
      }

      String? adversaryToken = userDoc.get('fcmToken') as String?;
      if (adversaryToken == null || adversaryToken.isEmpty) {
        print("DEBUG: FCM token missing for adversary.");
        return;
      }
      print("DEBUG: Retrieved FCM token: $adversaryToken");

      // Initialize Cloud Functions
      FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west2');
      print("DEBUG: Initialized Cloud Functions.");

      if (title.isEmpty) {
        throw Exception('Notification title is required');
      }
      if (body.isEmpty) {
        throw Exception('Notification body is required');
      }


      // Call the Cloud Function with the adversary's token, title, and body
      HttpsCallable callable = functions.httpsCallable('sendChallengeNotification');
      final response = await callable.call({
        'adversaryToken': adversaryToken,
        'title': title,
        'body': body,
      });

      print("DEBUG: Notification sent successfully. Response: $response");
    } catch (e) {
      print("DEBUG: Error sending notification: $e");
      if (e is FirebaseException) {
        print("DEBUG: Firebase Error Code: ${e.code}");
        print("DEBUG: Firebase Error Message: ${e.message}");
      }
    }
  }

-d '{  "name": "Hello World" }'me@cloudshell:~ (ratemyproject-68373)$ curl -X POST https://sendchallengenotification-5015312267.europe-west2.run.app \

-H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d '{  "name": "Hello World" }'
{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}me@cloudshell:~ (ratemyproject-68373)$

In Google Cloud, i already gave the autorisations to allUsers.
Any idea?
Thanks for advance, for you time.
Edit : @Frank van Puffelen thanks for your answer. Like i wrote it, i already put the good rights and i showed my firebase tools cli login, that show an error. Thanks

I had to use firebase cli tools to authenticate the machine itself.
"Theres this topics thtat have a lot of solutions:
Click the linked name of the function to which you want to grant access.
Click the Powered By Cloud Run link in the top right corner of the Function details overview page.
Click Trigger and select Allow unauthenticated invocations.
Click Save."
From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151247/newly-created-firebase-functions-throwing-unauthenticated-error
But I think you can try firebase tools cli login first.
